# Laravel Blade check user role

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

In laravel Blade templating we can exclude some parts of HTML with this code:

```
        @if (Auth::user())
            <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Mein Profil</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Mein Profil</a></li>
        @endif
```

If user is authenticated then show home and admin links and if user is not authenticated then show only home link.

My question is how to make a check here if user is admin?

I have default login system from laravel and i just added one more column in table users -> ('admin') with tinyint value 1 and in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbNKRr97uVs
i found the code for checking if user is admin

```
 if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->admin )
```

and it works in AdminMiddleware.php
but it doesn't work in blade. How to make this working??

Comment: Try to logout and login again, it may be because of you added column after loggedin and that may not be loaded ins Auth::user session. also add your dump response of this `echo "<pre>"; print_r(Auth::user()); die()` in your question, So we can see that admin column is coming or not

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I made a check route and with this it prints out check OK       Route::get('check', function() {
    echo 'check OK';
});      and with this          Route::get('check', function() {
 print_r(Auth::user());
});    prints nothing.....not even an error!

Comment: Sorry guys but it works now.....i think i needed just to reset the server :( my bad

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find such a long winded, check if logged in, check role, being added all around my blade files to distracting.  You may consider adding a custom blade directive. Add something like this to AppServiceProvider boot() function

```
Blade::if('admin', function () {            
    return auth()?->user()?->admin === true;
});
```

in blade just use

```
@admin
<p>Only admin sees this</p>
@endadmin
```

Comment: Related: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#extending-blade

Answer (score 4):

```
            @if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->admin)
                <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Mein Profil</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
            @else
                <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Mein Profil</a></li>
            @endif
```

this works just to be clear (just add one more column tinyint 'admin' in user table and set to 1)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method>  **HasRole**

You can call this from *artisan tinker* from command line, just to see it *before writing code*:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Check if the user with id 1 has role 'user';

```
User::find(1)->hasRole('user');
```

Check if the user with id 1 has role 'admin';

```
User::find(1)->hasRole('admin');
```

The same way while coding for example in app.blade template:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Main Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
 @else
        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Main Profile</a></li>
 @endif
```

[image]

The method hasRoles comes from the package spatie/laravel-permission

composer.json:
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.16"

[image]

full path of the class:
***vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasRoles.php***

Comment: where does this method come from? `->hasRole()` this seems not to be part of Laravel

Comment: The method hasRole($roles, string $guard = null): bool        -->  is part of the vendor "spatie/laravel-permission" package. Full path:  \vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasRoles.php