# Conditional menu items based on User Role

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm getting stuck on something that should be simple.

Using Laravel 5.3. I have a function setup for `User::isAdmin()` that can both check if a user has a given role.

I have some conditional menu items that should only appear for admins. how can I check for a role within a blade view file?

I have my many-to-many relationship setup and working fine for Users and Roles. When I try something along the lines of `auth()->user()->isAdmin()` or `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`, I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::isAdmin()

Here's a copy of my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Role;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'email', 'tax_id', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone','password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
    /**
     * Find specified user role by id or name
     * @param  [type]  $uid  user_id
     * @param  [type]  $role either name or id
     * @return boolean       [description]
     */
    static function hasRole($uid, $role){
        $user = User::find($uid);

        if(is_numeric($role)){
            foreach ($user->roles as $r) {
                // var_dump($r->id);
                if($r->id == $role){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            foreach ($user->roles as $r) {
                if($r->name == $role){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    public function isAdmin(){
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

            foreach ($user->roles as $r) {
                if($r->id == 1){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008388/laravel-blade-check-user-role?

Comment: `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` doesn't work for me either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680911/how-to-check-user-is-admin-or-not-in-laravel-blade-view?

Comment: that question's replies don't work for me either. I've updated my question with more details.